# 20.04 LTS upgrade options - nothing works

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 20.04

***Summary:*** I'm on 18.04.4 LTS, reading instructions from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes), I can't get any of the desktop update instructions to work.

**Option 1**
Using `Alt+F2` and typing `update-manager -c -d`

- this bring up an Upgrade button, and stays that 20.04 LTS is avaialble.
- when I click upgrade....**nothing**. tried a few times.

**Option 2**
Using: "If not you can run  `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk`"

I get:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk:30: 
PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
```

This sounds like a Python import error...but I'm not sure how to fix this?

**Option 3**
Use `do-release-upgrade -c` - this is with `Prompt=lts`. Again, it can't find an LTS release.

**Summing up**
From my less than expert view, it seems update manager can't see the same information as `do-release-upgrade` and I have some import errors with Python.

Should I just wait for 20.04.4?

Comment: `do-release-upgrade -d` ? "Should I just wait?" It depends.

Comment: The upgrade path has not been openwed yet. Upgrading 18.04 to 20.04 is not recommended till the end of July.

Comment: thanks @Pilot6 . @pLumo - I get `Please install all available updates for your release before`, digging into this I can see: `The following packages have been kept back:
  colord simple-scan` using `sudo apt-get upgrade -y`. then `The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 colord : Depends: libsane1 (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: You have broken your package system. Try to fix it by `sudo apt install -f`. Also  everything installed from PPAs should be removed by `ppa-purge` before an upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the pointers in the comments.

**My solution:** remove `libsane1` and `libsane-common` as I did not need them.

Doing a `sudo apt-get upgrade` showed no packages were being held back or issues that I not in the comments on the question.

Then ran `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` - this time it didn't complain about updating my system. The OS upgrade is underway...

Comment: Except for the fact that you chose the -d option, and you're going to get the development version, maybe not the final stable version...